# add error message to the current Validation Summary

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a collection of textbox that created dynamically (through button click), and all the textbox are required. An error message should be added to the current validation summary once the textbox is empty.Any help on how to do this one.

Javascript Code

```
var rowsid = 0;
    // Add button functionality
    $("#btnAddButton").live("click", function () {
        rowsid++;
        var master = $(this).parents().find("table.dynamictable"); //$(this).parents("table.dynatable");

        // Get a new row based on the prototype row
        var prot = master.find(".prototype").clone();
        prot.attr("class", "");
        prot.find(".id").attr("value", "00000" + rowsid);
        master.find("tbody").append(prot);
    });
```

HTML Code

```
<div class="msg-body">
        <table class="dynamictable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="display: none"></th>
                    <th>Package Name</th>
                    <th>Package Cost</th>
                    <th>No. of Attendees</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="prototype">
                    <td style="display: none"><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="" class="id" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="packagename[]" value="" class="pkname" data-val-required="This field is required"  /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="packagecost[]" value="0" class="pkcost" style="text-align: right" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="noofattendees[]" value="0" class="nfattendees" style="text-align: right"/></td>
                    <td>@Html.ActionImage("", null, "~/Content/Images/delete.gif", "Delete", new { @class = "deleterows" }) </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div style="padding:20px 0 20px 100px "><input type="button" id="btnAddButton" value="Add New" class="button addbutton"/></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function refreshValidation() {
    $("form").removeData("validator");
    $("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
}
```

This will revalidate texboxes that you added dynamically

Comment: do i need to add the data-val-required attribute to the textboxes or it will works as it is? and I need to call the refreshvalidation on click button?

Comment: Model: public string Name - For example should have [Required] attribute

Comment: Please see the updated question, I have put the the code for you to see how it looks.

Comment: Can you explain why don't you do everything this with partial views?

Comment: well, I am new to MVC3, I don't know what are the advantages of partial views over the approach that I have created.

Comment: All I need to do, is to create a dynamic data without making postback and pass all the data to the controller and add them as batch, not one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML5 `required="required"` attribute, but it won't work in old versions of IE

```
<input type="text" name="usrname" required="required" />
```

Detailed explanation - http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_required.asp

Comment: You should go with one of these - http://speckyboy.com/2009/12/17/10-useful-jquery-form-validation-techniques-and-tutorials-2/